# Subtracting dates from 2 different tables with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to Select all records in the claims data where the “from_date” field is before the “eff_date” for the same “emp_ssn”, same “pt_ssn”, in the "patient data".

```
SELECT *
FROM CLAIM 
   left join PATIENT on claim.pt_ssn = Patient.pt_ssn
WHERE (CLAIM.emp_ssn = Patient.emp_num AND Patient.pt_ssn=Claim.pt_ssn) 
  AND (CLAIM.FROM_DATE < Patient.eff_date);
```

This is giving me undesired results also with duplicates.

I have tried left join, right join, inner join, and no join. I still cannot receive desired result.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a `join` on the 2 `pt_ssn` columns, and then compare them again in the `WHERE`? That is redundant ... was that just trial and error?

Comment: Also, can you provide the table specs for the `CLAIM` and `PATIENT` tables? It'd be good to know the types of the date columns

Comment: This is a simpe join. Maybe you have duplicate data in the tables?! or you have missing join conditions?!

Comment: @Bean Taxi this was just a simple test forgot to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(CLAIM.emp_ssn = Patient.emp_num AND Patient.pt_ssn=Claim.pt_ssn)
```

The second part of the clause `Patient.pt_ssn=Claim.pt_ssn` is already mentioned in the `ON` clause so you don't need to mention it again.

Try this :

```
SELECT      CLAIM.*
FROM        CLAIM
left join   PATIENT on claim.pt_ssn = Patient.pt_ssn
WHERE       CLAIM.emp_ssn = Patient.emp_num
AND         CLAIM.FROM_DATE < Patient.eff_date
```

**EDIT** : I'm not sure what data set you have, but I think a simple group by should resolve your query.

I'll try my best to help you out :

Table : CLAIM

```
pt_ssn   emp_ssn   claim_name   from_date
1234        1       Claim_1     2015-05-10
2345        2       Claim_2     2015-07-10
3456        3       Claim_3     2015-09-10
4567        4       Claim_4     2015-11-10
5678        5       Claim_5     2015-12-10
5678        5       Claim_5     2015-12-04
6789        6       Claim_6     2015-12-12
```

Table : PATIENT

```
pt_ssn    emp_num        eff_date
 1234       1           2015-05-12
 2345       2           2015-07-08
 3456       3           2015-09-15
 4567       4           2015-11-07
 5678       5           2015-12-09
 5678       5           2015-12-12
 6789       6           2015-12-02
```

You can see that I have created duplicate records with the pt_ssn as 5678. Now, if I use the aforementioned query, namely :

```
SELECT      CLAIM.*
FROM        CLAIM
left join   PATIENT on claim.pt_ssn = Patient.pt_ssn
WHERE       CLAIM.emp_ssn = Patient.emp_num
AND         CLAIM.FROM_DATE < Patient.eff_date
```

then the result set I get is :

```
pt_ssn      emp_ssn claim_name  from_date
 1234       1       Claim_1     2015-05-10
 3456       3       Claim_3     2015-09-10
 5678       5       Claim_5     2015-12-04
 5678       5       Claim_5     2015-12-04       /*DUPLICATE ENTRY*/
 5678       5       Claim_5     2015-12-10
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/342d0/1

You can see the duplicate entry above. If you want to exclude such duplicate entries, you'll need to use `Group By` as follows :

```
 SELECT     CLAIM.pt_ssn,
            CLAIM.emp_ssn,
            CLAIM.claim_name,
            CLAIM.from_date
FROM        CLAIM
left join   PATIENT on #claim.pt_ssn = Patient.pt_ssn
WHERE       CLAIM.emp_ssn = Patient.emp_num
AND         CLAIM.FROM_DATE < Patient.eff_date
GROUP BY    CLAIM.from_date,
            CLAIM.pt_ssn,
            CLAIM.emp_ssn,
            CLAIM.claim_name
```

This will give you the result set as follows :

```
pt_ssn  emp_ssn claim_name  from_date
 1234   1       Claim_1     2015-05-10
 3456   3       Claim_3     2015-09-10
 5678   5       Claim_5     2015-12-04
 5678   5       Claim_5     2015-12-10
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/342d0/2

Observe that there are two entries for the pt_ssn : 5678. This is because they are for different dates.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Didn't work, I don't know whats going on to why it keeps producing duplicate data

Comment: @SikRikDaRula Can you provide some sample data so that we can better know the data we are dealing with?

Comment: Cool ... I did not know about SQL Fiddle. Upvoted for that. Good to know!

Comment: Its hard for me to actually provide any data as it contains a lot of patient information and I can't group it because there is over 150 fields. I am able to do an update query is what I really wanted which updates the desired 6519 rows correctly, but it seems to update the same row over and over. my claims data has over 55000 lines but when I update it says its updating close to 1.5 million lines. I realize its updating the correct rows, but this is really bad for performance. Also no single row in either table is duplicated. But the query returns duplicates.

Comment: `UPDATE Claim INNER JOIN Patient ON Claim.pt_ssn=Patient.pt_ssn SET Claim.reason_code_tmp = '10.07', Claim.remarks_tmp = '<Eff Date: ' & Patient.eff_date, Claim.overpaid_amt_1 = Claim.pay_1, Claim.overpaid_amt_2 = Claim.pay_2
WHERE (Claim.from_date<Patient.eff_date) And (Claim.reason_code_01<>"00" Or Claim.reason_code_01 Is Null);`

Comment: @SikRikDaRula This query is insufficient for me to help you out. If possible, provide a small subset (*sample table structure and sample data*) of the table structure. Update your question with these information and we'll be in a better position to understand your current scenario and help you out!!

Comment: So I was able to fix, I just added another query to remove duplicates before the update query, the pt_ssn were duplicated in the table... after removing all duplicates everything worked great. Thanks :) Sometimes its the small things you miss from hours of coding..lol

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there is a patient record even if there is no claim.. so the left join should be the other order.
Try this (or even list the fields you want returned):

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM PATIENT left join CLAIM 
on claim.pt_ssn = Patient.pt_ssn
and CLAIM.emp_ssn = Patient.emp_num
WHERE CLAIM.FROM_DATE < Patient.eff_date;
```